# How to handle 'object' dtypes variables in the Voting classifier using the lightgbm and xgboost frameworks?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, lightgbm, dtype

I am using the votingclassifier of sklearn with two classifiers(lightgbm and xgboost). All works fine whenever the input data consists of only numerical information (float and int dtype). It however raises an error whenever 'object' or 'category' dtypes variables are added to the data. Which is logic, since the lightgbm framework can handle 'category' variables, while the xgboost framework cannot.

What I want is to fit the two classifiers, within the votingclassifier, on same but essentially transformed data:

- For the xgboost algorithm I want to convert all 'object' or 'category' data to dummy data.
  (pd.get_dummies())
- For the lightgbm algorithm I want to convert all 'object' data to 'category' types.

Code:

```
    from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier

    clf = VotingClassifier(estimators = [('xgb', clf_xgb),
                           ('lgb', clf_lgb)], voting = 'soft')

    clf.fit(train[variables],train[target])
```

Comment: Probably you can give the `VotingClassifier` two `Pipeline` objects.  The xgboost model can make use of sklearn's `OneHotEncoder`, rather than `pd.get_dummies`, as the first step in its pipeline.  You might be able to make a custom transformer to fit lightgbm's required categorical format?

Comment: Or, cast all the categorical features to pandas `categorical`; then maybe lightgbm doesn't need a pipeline at all, and for xgboost you still just apply one-hot in a pipeline?